# How to render a partial with javascript in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, renderpartial

I am trying to use Javascript to render an `.html.erb` partial that itself contains safe Javascript.

`<%= render :partial => "tasks" %>` fails to render anything.

`<%= escape_javascript( render :partial => "tasks" ) %>` renders the HTML but the javascript is escaped, so it doesn't work.

How can I get both the HTML and its embedded Javascript to render properly?

Answer (score 0):

If the issue with <%= escape_javascript( render :partial => "tasks" ) %> is that the line is being escaped then <%= raw escape_javascript( render :partial => "tasks" ) %> should fix that.

If you want to learn more check out this link. http://yehudakatz.com/2010/02/01/safebuffers-and-rails-3-0/

Answer (score -1):

If the extension of the file is `.js.erb` then you can use `<%= escape_javascript( render :partial => "tasks" ) %>`,

Alternatively `<%= escape_javascript( render "tasks" ) %>`

Comment: That really doesn't answer the question.